# Pasar de JS a PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Hola quisiera usar la variable de JS y poder hacer un SELECT a la bd desde PHP.
Es posible usar esta variable de JS en PHP o hay alguna mejor solución?

```
 <script>var Var_JavaScript = '<p id="numero"></p>'; </script>



$numero = "<script> document.writeln(Var_JavaScript); </script>";
$sql="SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE id=('$numero') AND nombre IS NOT NULL ORDER BY nombre DESC LIMIT 1";  
    $result=pg_query($conexion,$sql);
      while($mostrar=pg_fetch_array($result)){  
    echo $mostrar['nombre'];

}if (pg_num_rows($result) == 1) {
echo "Bien";}else{echo "Mal";}
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Esta pregunta ya tiene respuesta aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/557494/46896

Answer (score 0):

Usando jquery podes por ajax enviar la variable js asincronicamente a un archivo de php, resolver lo que necesites y devolver datos.
Te paso un ejemplo

Archivo html + javascript (index.html)

```
<div id="resultado"></div>

<script>
    var numero_js = 8;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'backend.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {"numero":numero_js,
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#resultado").html(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Archivo php (backend.php)

```
$numero = $_POST['numero'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE id=('$numero') AND nombre IS NOT NULL ORDER BY nombre DESC LIMIT 1";  
$result=pg_query($conexion,$sql);

while($mostrar=pg_fetch_array($result)){  
    echo $mostrar['nombre'];
}
```

Recorda que todo lo que quieras devolver desde el archivo php tenes que hacerlo usando echo y no return. Si necesitas devolver mas de un dato podes devolver un JSON.